# Select nearest ancestor called "BATCH" in XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to select the first ancestor called "BATCH" going up in the XML Tree.

I've tried: `ancestor::BATCH` and `ancestor::BATCH[1]` but it's not working.

[XPATH 2.0]

Comment: "it's not working" - this is insufficient information for anyone to help you. Show us **what you did** - a sample of your xml, the code you are using to query it; **what you expected** - the results you want; and **what actually happened** - the results you got.

Comment: First thing to check: Is that `<BATCH>` ancestor namespaced? If so, you will need to use a namespace prefix in your XPath and tell the XPath processor what namespace this prefix is bound to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by first ancestor?

If you have an XML:

```
<!-- second ancestor -->
<BATCH>
    <a>
       <!-- first ancestor -->
       <BATCH>
           <b></b>
       </BATCH>
    </a>
</BATCH>
```

Assuming your context node is `<b>` you would use `ancestor::BATCH[1]` to select what I described as *first ancestor*

If however by first ancestor you mean the outermost ancestor, which I defined here as *second ancestor* you'd have to use `ancestor::BATCH[not(ancestor::BATCH)]`
to select the ancestor BATCH that doesn't have an ancestor BATCH.

---

If you have a namespace problem like @keshlam mentioned in his comment you can use

```
ancestor::*[local-name()='BATCH'][1]
```

To select it ignoring its namespace.